# Oracle - update the same count of duplicates between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables UPD_REF and UPD_TO

```
CREATE TABLE UPD_REF
( ref number(10)
);

CREATE TABLE UPD_TO
( ref number(10),
  name varchar2(50)
);

INSERT INTO UPD_REF (ref) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO UPD_REF (ref) VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO UPD_TO (ref, name) VALUES (1, 'ORG');
INSERT INTO UPD_TO (ref, name) VALUES (2, 'ORG');
INSERT INTO UPD_TO (ref, name) VALUES (2, 'ORG');
INSERT INTO UPD_TO (ref, name) VALUES (2, 'ORG');
INSERT INTO UPD_TO (ref, name) VALUES (3, 'ORG');
```

There is no key and we can have duplicates in both tables UPD_TO or UPD_REF.

I need to update the **same count of rows** on UPD_TO corresponding to UPD_REF.

If I do a simple update or merge like this:

```
merge into UPD_TO USING UPD_REF
on (UPD_TO.ref = UPD_REF.ref)
when matched then
update set UPD_TO.name = 'SET';
```

I have all the matching values updated:

```
REF  NAME
---- ----
   1 ORG 
   2 SET 
   2 SET 
   2 SET 
   3 SET
```

But I need to get that:

```
REF  NAME
---- ----
   1 ORG 
   2 SET 
   2 ORG 
   2 ORG 
   3 SET
```

Any clues ?

Comment: How do you identify the exact physical row to be updated for multiple IDs? And what is the purpose of duplicates in such narrow table?

Comment: I've simplified the problem as much as possible before asking the question. I am running oracle and I do not have many other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your rows by rowid, but first you need to identify that single row in each group by some ordering criteria in `ROW_NUMBER()`. [The code is](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c5f016e88c805b64ff6968e03447aec):

```
merge into upd_to
using (
  select t.rowid,
    row_number() over(
      partition by t.ref
      order by 1 /*Put your ordering to raise that single row to top of order by*/ asc
    ) as rn
  from UPD_TO t
  where ref in (
    select f.ref
    from upd_ref f
  )
) u
  on (upd_to.rowid = u.rowid and u.rn = 1)
when matched then update
  set name = 'SET'

| REF | NAME |
+-----+------+
|1    | ORG  |
|2    | ORG  |
|2    | ORG  |
|2    | SET  |
|3    | SET  |
```

If your table has more columns, then it may be good solution. If this is the exact table you have and you need to have a count of rows with the same `ID` and `NAME`, then it is better not to insert new rows, but update and count rows (of course, altering table before with new column for counter):

```
merge into UPD_TO
using (select <new data> ) new_data
on (UPD_TO.ref = new_data.ref)
when matched then update
  set item_count = item_count + new_data.item_count
when not matched then insert
  values(new_data.id, new_data.name, new_data.item_count)
```

I cannot imagine another useful reason to have such two-column table with duplicates, that's why I've asked for clarification of the purpose.

**UPD**: New version, that updates the same row count per `REF`, that `UPD_REF` has, with [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31fe5deb707f592d0e3385a7b07ed54c) containing duplicates in `UPD_REF`.

```
merge into upd_to
using (
  with base as (
    select t.rowid,
      t.ref,
      row_number() over(partition by t.ref order by 1) as rn
    from UPD_TO t
  )
  select rowid
  from base
  where (ref, rn) in (
    select
      f.ref,
      row_number() over(partition by f.ref order by 1) as rn2
    from upd_ref f
  )
) u
  on (upd_to.rowid = u.rowid)
when matched then update
  set name = 'SET'
```

Comment: The problem is when you have two '2' in the UPD_REF this code still update one (RN=1). I try to simplify the problem of course this is not a real world, in fact it will be dynamic SQL with a large amount of columns. thanx.

Comment: @BenoîtBottemanne You didn't put duplicates in your example, so I've missed trat point. Updated the query with rowcount in reference dataset.

Comment: I put in bold  "same count of rows", it is okay thanx ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the update statement with `EXISTS` as follows:

```
UPDATE UPD_TO T SET NAME = 'SET'
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY TT.ROWID) AS RN,
               TT.ROWID AS RID
          FROM UPD_TO TT
         WHERE TT.REF = T.REF
    ) WHERE RN <= (
        SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM UPD_REF R
         WHERE R.REF = T.REF
    ) AND RID = T.ROWID
);
```

(This is un-tested code, Please comment if it do not work for you)